# Query in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

```
SELECT PRJ_CC_id
, PROJECT_COSTCENTER_NAME
, AREA_ID
, AREA_Name
, Activity_ID
, Activity_Name
, SUM(Total)
FROM(
  (
    SELECT PRJ_CC_id
    , PROJECT_COSTCENTER_NAME
    , AREA_ID
    , AREA_Name
    , Activity_ID
    , Activity_Name
    , (SUM(mon) + SUM(tue) + SUM(wed) + SUM(thu) + SUM(fri) + SUM(sat) + SUM(
      sun)) Total
    FROM tr_view_masterlogentry
    WHERE USER_ID = 654321
    AND work_year = 2010
    GROUP BY PRJ_CC_id
    , PROJECT_COSTCENTER_NAME
    , AREA_ID
    , AREA_Name
    , Activity_ID
    , Activity_Name
    , mon
    , tue
    , wed
    , thu
    , fri
    , sat
    , sun
  )
UNION
  (
    SELECT PRJ_CC_id
    , PROJECT_COSTCENTER_NAME
    , AREA_ID
    , AREA_Name
    , Activity_ID
    , Activity_Name
    , Tot_Amt Total
    FROM tr_view_Exchange_loghours
    WHERE USER_ID                 = 654321
    AND TO_CHAR(adj_Date, 'yyyy') = 2010
    GROUP BY PRJ_CC_id
    , PROJECT_COSTCENTER_NAME
    , AREA_ID
    , AREA_Name
    , Activity_ID
    , Activity_Name
    , Tot_Amt
  )
  )
GROUP BY PRJ_CC_id
, PROJECT_COSTCENTER_NAME
, AREA_ID
, AREA_Name
, Activity_ID
, Activity_Name;
```

In this query when i execute it, it will make total of column 'Total' in sum function when values of both 'Total'column in union query is different like 31 and -2 and sum is 29

but when value of both 'Total' column in union query is same like 31 and 31 then it will show only 31 in sum

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UNION` should be `UNION ALL`. `UNION` will remove duplicates.

Comment: also note that `UNION ALL` is faster.